# proxy re-authentication required error in telegram bot

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

I use webhook to get updates but now the bot does not get them from telegram servers. I'm using laravel 5.8.  I checked webhook with getWebhookInfo and it returned

```
    {"ok":true,"result"{"url":"https://example.com/bot_commands","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":15,"last_error_date":1569065002,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 419 proxy reauthentication required","max_connections":40}}
```

How can I solve this error?. help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

419proxy reauthentication required means that CSRF Protection is enabled for your webhook route. CSRF protection should be disabled for only webhook routes, to do this, open file VerifyCsrfToken.php on your project.

dir — App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
<?phpnamespace App\Http\Middleware;use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier{  protected $except = [    'payment/*', // routes group    'specific-route', // specific route  ];}
```

for more example go to the official laravel documentation website: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris